# How should the ground wires be connected when changing my dryer's power cord from 3 prong to 4?

Tags: electrical, wiring, dryer

So we have this really old dryer (MayTag sde305dayw) and I've attempted to do the wiring from a 3 Prong to 4 Prong power cord (moved to a newer home) but when I plugged it in, it didn't turn on.

The confusion I have is there are two Green/Yellow wires connected to the body. There's also a blue wire where I connected the red one to, so hopefully that isn't something that could affect it either. Not sure what else to do at this point, don't want to cause damage to myself. [image: Images].

Comment: Disconnect the yellow-green latch from the body of the machine (it short-circuits neutral with PE).

Answer (score 5):

The [installation instructions](https://www.maytag.com/content/dam/global/documents/201108/installation-instructions-40136301.pdf) show you have wired it properly for a four wire cord. I would check the receptacle to verify it is wired correctly. [image]

Before you do anything if you haven't done it yet download the [installation instructions](https://www.maytag.com/content/dam/global/documents/201108/installation-instructions-40136301.pdf) from Maytag. It shows the green wire being connected to the center screw is just a placeholder for a jumper that is connected to the top of the neutral terminal via a spade stake-on. If you connect it to the ground you will be bonding the neutral to the ground as required for a 3-wire NEMA 10 connection.

If after connecting cord correctly I would confirm that the four wire receptacle is being fed by four wires, specifically to confirm a white wire is connected to the L-shaped terminal, green to the opposite terminal, and 240v between the parallel flat blades.

Beyond that your problem sounds like it could be internal to the dryer, way beyond my ability to advise without more pictures.

If you move the jumper and the dryer receptacle is missing a functioning neutral the dryer (if in working order) would illegally operate by running the 120v circuitry on the ground.

Comment: Regarding the blue wire,  the wiring diagram for the dryer  https://www.ereplacementparts.com/maytag-sde305dayw-residential-maytag-laundry-parts-c-461666_462525_464002.html shows two BU wires connected to L2 and a BK and YL connected to L1. The image kind of looks like L1 & L2 only have single stakes, it is possible that Maytag connected multiple wires in a single stake-on, or the daisychained those connections internally, but it might be worth looking around for some disconnected wires.

Comment: The second smaller ground wire (below the L1 termination) looks like a typical jumper that is installed between components (like to the control facia) to insure that the chassis ground isn't dependent on the mechanical fasteners that hold the dryer together. Jumpers of that type are often omitted from the wiring diagrams.